# /boot driver filling up due to kernels on 11.10 and unable to update

Tags: 11.10, boot, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove/hide old kernel versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

Any clean solutions for cleaning up the /boot mount?  It seems to fill with kernels but I'd like to make sure the overall package management knows they are gone.

Do you really need to remove one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like uninstalling them one by one, install synaptic, start it, search for "linux" there - it'll show you the list of your kernels.

tick-tick-tick; Uninstall; Apply. Done.

Answer (score 4):

What I can guess is that you might to remove the old kernels. You can do this by

1. `uname -r`

[image: uname -r]

Note down the current version of kernel

```
dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | grep '^ii'
```

[image: output of dpkg -l linux-image-...]

Note down the kernel version(s) (the numbers after the linux-image, ie x.y.z.-generic) 
(Include "-generic too")

Then run this command to delete old kernels WARNING : DO NOT DELETE THE KERNEL WHOSE  VERSION YOU PREVIOUSLY NOTED DOWN IN "uname -r"

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.y.z-generic
```

(In my case it will be `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.0.0.13` since linux-image-3.0.0.15 is the version I noted down in "uname -r")

Lastly update grub with the commands

```
sudo update-grub2
```

or

```
sudo update-grub
```

(Running both wont do any harm to the computer)

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks...thats a bit what I was concerned about.  The one by one approach

Comment: dpkg -l 'linux-image-[0-9]*' | grep '^ii' | grep -v \`uname -r\` | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge -y # close eyes and press Enter